# Problem with accessing variables on different pages

Tags: php, laravel

I need to be able to access certain variables throughout the whole application (in all blade files). Currently I am just able to access them on one page and that page is set up in controller (profile.show). I successfully managed to access one of those variables with view composer in AppServiceProvider.php but I am unable to do so for others. When I dump them on some other blade it shows error that is not defined but profile_details works fine. I need help on how to put those variables ($profile, $data, $options, $photos) in AppServiceProvider.php composer in order to be able to access them. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

AppServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\User;
use App\UserProfile;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder; // Import Builder where defaultStringLength method is defined

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */


    public function boot()
    { 
        view()->composer('*', function ($view) {
            $view->with('profile_details', Auth::id() ? UserProfile::profileDetails(Auth::id(), Auth::id()) : []);  
        });

        Builder::defaultStringLength(191); // Update defaultStringLength
    }

}
```

UserProfileController.php

```
class UserProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function showProfile($username, Request $request)
    {
        $user = $request->user();
        $viewer = User::find(Auth::id());
        $owner = User::where('username', $username)->first();

        if($viewer->id !== $owner->id && !$owner->active){
            abort(404);
        }

        if(!$profileId = User::getIdFromUsername($username)){
            abort(404);
        }

        $profile = UserProfile::profileDetails($profileId, $viewer->id);

        $data = UserProfile::getProfileLookingFor(Auth::user()->id);

        $options = UserProfile::getProfileLookingForDisplayOptions();

        $details = $this->returnDropdowns();


        $photo = new Photo();
        $photos = $photo->managePhotos();

        return view('profile.show', compact('user', 'profile', 'data', 'options', 'details', 'photos'));
    }
}
```

UserProfile.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\User;

use App\Value;
use App\FieldValue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;


class UserProfile extends Model

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public static function profileData($profileId, $viewerId)
    {
        $user = User::find($viewerId);
        $profile = DB::table('users as u')
            ->select(DB::raw("
                data.*,
                u.id, u.gender_id, u.username, u.email, u.password, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.age, u.date_of_birth, u.premium, u.active, u.job, u.mobile_number
            "))
            ->leftJoin('user_profiles as data', 'data.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
            ->where('u.id', $profileId)
            ->first();

        return $profile;
    }

    public static function profileDetails($profileId, $viewerId)
    {
        $profile = static::profileData($profileId, $viewerId);

        if ($profile) {
            if ($viewerId != $profileId) {
                # Viewer is displaying another user's profile.
                $myProfile = false;
                } else {
                    $myProfile = true;
                }
            }

        $unit = FieldValue::measure();
        $height = App::make('App\FieldValue')->height($profile->height, $unit);

            $profile = [
                'viewerId' => $viewerId,
                'profile_id' => $profileId,
                'myProfile' => $myProfile,
                'height' => $height,
                'personal_quote' => $profile->personal_quote,
                'about_me' => $profile->about_me,
                'astro' => UserAstro::all(),
                'bodyType' => UserBodyType::all(),
                'children' => UserChildren::all(),
                'education' => UserEducation::all(),
                'orientation' => UserOrientation::all(),
                'relationshipStatus' => UserRelationshipStatus::all(),
                'smoke' => UserSmoke::all(),
            ];

        return $profile;
    }

    public static function getProfileLookingFor($userId)
    {
        $results = DB::table('user_interests')
            ->select('field_id', 'value_id')
            ->where('user_id', $userId)
            ->orderBy('field_id')
            ->get();

        $data = [];
        if (! empty($results)) {
            foreach ($results as $result) {
                if (isset($data[$result->field_id])) {
                    array_push($data[$result->field_id], $result->value_id);
                } else {
                    $data[$result->field_id] = [$result->value_id];
                }
            }
        }

        return $data;
    }

    public static function getProfileLookingForDisplayOptions()
    {
        $options = [
            'gender' => ['id' => 1, 'label' => "Interessiert an"],
            'looking_for' => ['id' => 2, 'label' => ""]
        ];

        $data_options = [];
        foreach ($options as $field => $value) {
            $data_options[$field]['data'] = Value::fieldValues($field);
            $data_options[$field]['label'] = $options[$field];

            if (!in_array($field, ['gender', 'looking_for'])) {
                $data_options[$field]['data'][100] = "Doesn't matter";
            }
        }

        return $data_options;
    }

    public function postProfileLookingFor($userId, Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        $options = [
            'gender'         => 1,
            'looking_for'    => 2
        ];

        foreach ($options as $fieldName => $fieldId) {
            if (! empty($data[$fieldName])) {
                DB::table('user_interests')
                    ->where('user_id', $userId)
                    ->where('field_id', $fieldId)
                    ->delete();

                if (is_array($data[$fieldName])) { // Checkboxes
                    foreach ($data[$fieldName] as $key => $value) {
                        DB::table('user_interests')->insert([
                            'user_id'  => $userId,
                            'field_id' => $fieldId,
                            'value_id' => $value
                        ]);
                    }
                } else { // Select fields
                    DB::table('user_interests')->insert([
                        'user_id'  => $userId,
                        'field_id' => $fieldId,
                        'value_id' => $data[$fieldName]
                    ]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `View::share` to access a variable in all views:

In the `boot` method of the `AppServiceProvider` do the following:

```
public function boot() {

    $profile_details = Auth::id() ? UserProfile::profileDetails(Auth::id(), Auth::id()) : [];

    View::share('profile_details', $profile_details);

    Builder::defaultStringLength(191); // Update defaultStringLength
}
```

[Documentation on `View::share`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#sharing-data-with-all-views)

Comment: But my variable $profile_details works fine. I need help on other four

Comment: Could you move all the logic for those four variables to the AppServiceProvider? If not, why wouldn't you?

Comment: Well maybe I could. I am trying that now but I always get errors that some of the variables are not declared. Can you help me a little?

Comment: That usually means that some of the input variables would be empty. Check if all the function parameters are correct. Also you depend on a user being logged in, check if you're logged in and make sure that when you're not, you have a fallback.

Comment: Ok I try to make it work with $options variable. I put this in AppServiceProvider.php  $options = Auth::id() ? UserProfile::getProfileLookingForDisplayOptions(Auth::id(), Auth::id()) :[];

        View::share('options', $options);    and now it says that Trying to get property 'id' of non-object from UserProfileController on $viewer variable

Comment: @mrmar Seems to me that the part you put into the ASP works, but the part in the UPC doesn't and are two separate pieces. At least, that how it feels to me.

Comment: Yeah, I commented code in controller and now I guess it works. Thank you very much!